# Using SELECTEDVALUE with PowerPivot instead of Power BI

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I moved a report from Power BI to Power Pivot, but the formula of SELECTEDVALUE does not exist in Power Pivot.
Can you help correct to a function that works in Power Pivot?

```
las_val = 
VAR y =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DateTime[Gasday] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        HEML_TTF_PRICE_V[TTF_DA_WE],
        TOPN (
            1,
            FILTER (
                ALLSELECTED ( DateTime[Gasday] ),
                DateTime[Gasday] <= y
                    && NOT ( ISBLANK ( HEML_TTF_PRICE_V[TTF_DA_WE] ) )
            ),
            DateTime[Gasday], DESC
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECTEDVALUE is a newer function that's a shortcut for

```
IF ( HASONEVALUE ( DateTime[GasDay] ), VALUES ( DateTime[GasDay] ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your try. I am pretty sure there is more to code than that, so if you know how to adjust the full code, I would be very happy.

Comment: Replace the SELECTEDVALUE line with what I wrote. The rest stays the same.

Comment: Thanks for try, it does not work, it actually gives the double value on days with values, and still blanks on days without values. Perhaps I am not understanding the issue well enough.

Comment: In that case, your problem is somewhere else. The substitution I gave is how SELECTEDVALUE is defined.

Comment: Ok, but I know how it is defined. What I don't know, is how to use it all in practise.

Comment: I managed to find my error. The formula above is the correct to use and swap with SelectedValue. My own error was, that I join the calendar table on the wrong coloumn date. Thanks for help